# c# linq to xml subnodes query

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an xml of the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<solution>
  <file>
    <song>foo1.mp3</song>
    <listen>
      <number>1</number>
      <data>
        <date>2013.08.21</date>
        <user>user1</user>
        <spec>foo</spec>
      </data>
    </listen>
    <listen>
      <number>2</number>
      <data>
        <date>2013.08.23</date>
        <user>user2</user>
        <spec>foo</spec>
      </data>
    </listen>
  </file>
  <file>
    <song>foo2.mp3</song>
    <listen>
      <number>1</number>
      <data>
        <date>2013.08.21</date>
        <user>user1</user>
        <spec>foo</spec>
      </data>
    </listen>
    <listen>
      <number>2</number>
      <data>
        <date>2013.08.23</date>
        <user>user2</user>
        <spec>foo</spec>
      </data>
    </listen>
  </file>
</solution>
```

How to query date, user or spec where song and number is variable?

Maybe i can change xml file format or somethings else.

I am using c#.

For example, I would like to see all the dates listening to the song, or the user who listened to the songs as a second

thank you

For add to listbox all song i use:

```
var proj = from nodes in System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Load(foo.xml).Elements("file") select nodes;

            if (proj != null)
            {
                foreach (var b in proj)
                {
                    plist.Items.Add(b.Element("song").Value.Trim());
                }
            }
```

but i don't know how show for example date for all numbers or user for song foo and number 2

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
var song = "foo2.mp3";
var number = 2;

var query =
    from x in xd.Root.Elements("file")
    where x.Element("song").Value == song
    from y in x.Elements("listen")
    where (int)y.Element("number") == number
    select y.Element("data");
```

Which would give you:

[image: result]